# Find the area of a right trapezoid

Tags: geometry

In the figure, $ABCD$ is a right trapezoid. $E$ is the midpoint of $[AD]$, $|AB|=12cm, |BC|=18cm,$ and $A(DCE)=15 cm^2.$

What is the area of $ABCD$?

[image]

My attempt is:

$\Delta ABE: 144+ED^2=EB^2$

$\Delta DEC: ED^2+DC^2=EC^2$

$\Delta CEB: EC^2+EB^2=BC^2$

$ED^2+DC^2+144+ED^2=324$

$2ED^2+DC^2=180$

But I didn't now how to continue.

The solution is: $30; 60; 45\sqrt 3; 90 cm^2$

Help me please.

Comment: Is E the middle if $[AD]? $ in the figure.

Comment: The upper right corner should be $C$, not $E$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $|DE|=x$ and call the upper right corner $C$.  Drop a perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$, making a right triangle with the $18$ as hypotenuse.  We have $|DF|=\frac {30}x$ from the area of $DCE$, so the horizontal leg of the triangle is $12-\frac {30}x$.  Write $(2x)^2+(12-\frac {30}x)^2=18^2$, solve for $x$, then the area of the trapezoid is $x(12+\frac {30}x)$

Comment: Yes, I no that the upper rigt corner is C, but where is F in the figure

Comment: It must be solved equation form: 4x^4-180x^2-720x+900=0

Comment: I meant $C$ to drop the perpendicular from.  I started calling it $F$, then noticed that you used $C$ and only updated one of them.  Fixed